Modal Timer keeps Getting Faster?
I'm creating a script that uses a modal timer, but I noticed that every time I call it, it goes faster with no way for me to reverse it. How would I reset it to the initial timer rate? It's based on the default modal timer in the templates section, and I noticed that that script has the same issue. Is it because it keeps adding handlers, or another problem? Below is the problematic section of code. Any help would be appreciated?
    """Operator which runs itself from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Builder"

    _timer = None
    
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        global counter
        vis_run = context.scene.vis_run
        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            counter += 1
            print (counter)
            if not vis_run:
                vis_run = False
                return {"FINISHED"}
            else:
                if counter <= 25:
                    bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup"].nodes["Mix"].inputs[7].default_value = (1,0,0,1)
                    bpy.data.materials["Glow"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = 0
                else:
                    bpy.data.node_groups["NodeGroup"].nodes["Mix"].inputs[7].default_value = (.3,.3,.3,1)
                    bpy.data.materials["Glow"].node_tree.nodes["Mix"].inputs[0].default_value = 1
            
        if counter == 35: 
            counter = 0
            

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        context.scene.vis_run = True
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(.01, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}```


That is due to the fact that every time the execute method is called, it adds a new timer handler without removing the previous one. So the timers keep adding up giving the impression that it's speeding up. Don't forget to clear the timer when the operator exits.

To iterate on the comment you want this I believe : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.event_timer_remove eg context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer); return {"FINISHED"}
